# Change RelativeLayout To ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have created an app that consists of a `RelativeLayout`. After adding in all the information the `RelativeLayout` is too small to fit all the information in. I need to be able to scroll up and down using the `ScrollView` layout. I have tired replacing the word `RelativeLayout` with `ScrollView` as well as adding the `ScrollView` inside the `RelativeLayout` but then my app crashes. So not sure where to put the `ScrollView`.

#### main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/GifImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/GifImageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/GifImageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnNextScreen"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cbk1"

        android:text="CickABle CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:text="CickABle CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:text="CickABle CheckBox" />
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNextScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="NEXT SCREEN" />

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollView must have one child ,so if you have one more child it will crash

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/black"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/GifImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

      <mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/GifImageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

      <mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/GifImageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNextScreen"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
          android:id="@+id/cbk1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="CickABle CheckBox"/>

        <CheckBox
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="CickABle CheckBox"/>

        <CheckBox
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"


          android:text="CickABle CheckBox"/>
      </LinearLayout>


      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="NEXT SCREEN"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AnonymousZA @Vir Rajpurohit You need to add `width="match_parent"` and `height="wrap_content"` for Inner RelativeLayout to work with ScrollView

Comment: @RutvikBhatt Edited! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong. Always remeber tha `ScrollView must have one child` and Also you need to make your `ScrollView` your parent layout. Try doing it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/GifImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/GifImageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <mudasir.com.gifsimages.GIF.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/GifImageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNextScreen"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbk1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="CickABle CheckBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:text="CickABle CheckBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:text="CickABle CheckBox" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="NEXT SCREEN" />
</RelativeLayout>
```